# How do I secure "hanging" front facing pavers?

Tags: adhesive, patio, pavers

I have a stone walkway and steps up to my front door, and the front facing pavers/stones on the top step have come loose yet again.  When I put them back up, in order to have them flush at the top of the stair, there is about 1/2 in gap on the bottom.  It looks fine, but I think the lack of support on the bottom is causing these things to repeatedly fall down.

Should I just find some slightly larger pavers?  Or should I build up the bottom layer with something to offer support?  If I did this I think I would only want it in the back so it was not visible.  Or should I try the same approach with some possibly better adhesive (any recommendations here?) and convince my 4 year old daughter to stop standing directly on these "hanging" stones?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. A picture of the problem would really help us. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: larger pavers will help as will some sort of glue, what is under the pavers?

Comment: Got to have pictures. Show us the gaps, what's underneath, and how the pavers fit into the steps, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try the Gorilla Ultimate Construction Adhesive. Your four year old will be grown up before you know it and won't be a problem anymore. Good luck.